# MarkLogic Java API batch upload files (.csv)

Tags: csv, file-upload, marklogic, java

Im trying out the MarkLogic Java API and would want to bulk upload some files with the extension .csv

I'm not sure what to use, since the Java API only supports JSON, XML, and TXT files.

How do I batch upload files using the MarkLogic Java api? Do i convert everything to JSON?

Comment: csv is txt so you should be ok. If you are doing bulk uploading perhaps marklogic content pump (mlcp) would be a faster way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

> Do i convert everything to JSON?

Yes, that is a common way to do it.

If you would like additional examples of how you can wrangle CSV with the Java Client API, check out [OpenCSVBatcherExample](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/marklogic/client/example/extension/OpenCSVBatcherExample.java) and [JacksonDatabindTest.testDatabindingThirdPartyPojoWithMixinAnnotations](https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/marklogic/client/test/JacksonDatabindTest.java#L152).  The first demonstrates converting the csv to XML and using a custom REST extension.  The second example (well, unit test...) demonstrates converting the csv to JSON and using the batch upload (Bulk Writes) capabilities Justin linked to.

Answer (score 2):

If you have CSV files on your filesystem, I’d start with mlcp, as suggested above. It will handle all of the parsing and splitting into multiple transactions/batches for you. Take a look at the [mlcp documentation](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_92863) for more details and some example configurations.

If you’d like more control over the parsing and splitting logic than mlcp gives you out-of-the-box or you’re getting CSV from some other source (i.e. not files on the filesystem), you can use the Java Client API. The Java Client API allows you to efficiently write batches using a `WriteSet`. Take a look at the [“Bulk Writes” example](http://developer.marklogic.com/features/java-client-api-2).

Comment: Hi! I have to integrate it as a web portal :( and no through command line

Answer (score 1):

According to your reply to Justin, you cannot use MLCP because it is command line and you need to integrate it into a web portal.

Well, MLCP is released as open cource software under the Apache2 licence. So if you are happy with this licence, then you have the source to integrate.

But what I see as your main problem statement is more specific:
*How can I create miltiple XML OR JSON documents from a CSV file [allowing the use of the java API to then upload them as documents in MarkLogic]*

With that specific problem statement:

1) have a look at SplitDelimitedTextReader.java from the mlcp source
2) try some java libraries for this purpose such as http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/quick-tutorial.html